# Duplicating C:\ drive hidden from Windows XP in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, windows-explorer

When I installed a stock copy of Windows XP on an older computer of mine recently (which eventually got replaced with Ubuntu because of driver and security reasons), I noticed something that really stood out to me. It was that when I typed C:\ into the address bar of Windows Explorer, it didn't show me any files. Instead, it showed me a notice that the folder was hidden and that modifying its contents would lead to trouble. I rarely if ever have to actually modify the C:\ drive unless I'm poking around where I'm not supposed to (and things more often than not break when I do that), and the feature just seemed correct for most purposes and users. I am looking for a way to duplicate this in Windows 10.

Clarification: I do not want the entire drive hidden, just the parts of it that shouldn't normally be visible to a user.

I tried hiding it like any other file/folder, opening up the Properties window, etc. but the check box was not there. I do not know if hiding a folder also hides everything under it, which would prevent the other obvious-ish option I thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I have duplicated this by selecting all of the files and folders in the C:\ folder and hiding them (and selecting "hide this folder only" and not "apply to all subfolders, etc."), and then by executing this command in an elevated Powershell. It's not as fancy as what I saw in the earlier version of Windows, but it will do for me.

```
echo "Don't modify this folder as it may damage your system." > C:\DO_NOT_MODIFY_THIS_FOLDER.txt
```